# Matching a substring (an apostrophe) in a given word using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a server application which looks up where the stress is in Russian words. The end user writes a word ***жажда***. The server downloads a page from another server which contains the stresses indicated with *apostrophes* for each case/declension like this ***жа'жда***. I need to find that word in the downloaded page.

In Russian the stress is always written after a vowel. I've been using so far a regex that is a grouping of all possible combinations ***(жа'жда|жажда')***. Is there a more elegant solution **using just a regex pattern** instead of making a PHP script which creates all these combinations?

EDIT:

1. I have a word ***жажда***
2. The downloaded page contains the string ***жа'жда***. (notice the
   apostrophe, I do not before-hand know where the apostrophe in the
   word is)
3. I want to match the word with apostrophe (***жа'жда***).

P.S.: So far I have a PHP script creating the string ***(жа'жда|жажда')*** used in regex (apostrophe is only after vowels) which matches it. My goal is to get rid of this script and use just regex in case it's possible.

Comment: Are you matching one word at a time? Or is it in a longer string?

Comment: Are you simply trying to replace every single vowel in a given string by the same vowel followed by an apostrophe using PHP?

Comment: @Sam Yes, one word at a time.

Comment: @Jerome Simply said, I have a given word and somewhere in it (or at the end) is an apostrophe.

Comment: @AMDcze I am not sure to understand, you have been using a regex, and want regex instead of php

Comment: @AMDcze - Re-reading your question, can you confirm that if you provide `жажда`, you will get as a result both `жа'жда` and `жажда'` because there are two vowels?  And if your input is `жажда жа` for example, you would get 3 results:  `жа'жда`, `жажда'` and `жа'`?

Comment: @PaulH I have a PHP script which creates a string of all possible combinations like this one ***(di'sorder|diso'rder|disorde'r)*** (the apostrophe is only after a vowel) and I use this string in regex. The page that is being matched would contain diso'rder, because the stress in English in on the letter ***o***. I'm looking for a way to get rid of this extra scripting and use just regex.

Comment: @AMDcze So you want to run that on the client instead of on the server. are you using java or javascript?

Comment: @PaulH I want to run that on the server side. I'm using just PHP (and HTML). The user wants to see where the stress is in a given word (i.e. disorder). The PHP script downloads a page which contains information about the word disorder and the word with apostrophe denoting where the stress is (diso'rder) and returns this string with an apostrophe to the user.

Comment: With given word and somewhere in it (or at the end) is an apostrophe, what do you want to do with a regex? See if there is an apostrophe after a vowel?

Comment: @PaulH And I only have the string disorder to begin with, I do not know where the apostrophe is going to be.

Comment: regex is used to match patterns, to find something. When you want to use regex, what do you want to find in e.g. disorder? the i, the  o and the e and replace them with i', o' and e'?

Comment: @PaulH Okay, even easier said. I have these options ***(d'isorder|di'sorder|dis'order|diso'rder|disor'der|disord'er|disorde'r|disorder')*** and one of these is in the downloaded page and I need to find out which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, 
*have these options (d'isorder|di'sorder|dis'order|diso'rder|disor'der|disord'er|disorde'r|disorder‌​') and one of these is in the downloaded page and I need to find out which one it is*
this may suit your needs:

```
<pre>
<?php
$s = "d'isorder|di'sorder|dis'order|diso'rder|disor'der|disord'er|disorde'r|disorder'|disorde'";
$s = explode("|",$s);
print_r($s);
$matches = preg_grep("@[aeiou]'@", $s);
print_r($matches);
```

running example: https://eval.in/207282

Comment: But the word is based on user's input and I have to have a function for creating $s. What I already have is this, which works, but I'm looking just if I can do it with regex and not extra PHP scripting:  
`function possibleOptions($word) { ... } ` 
  
`preg_match("#(".possibleOptions($_POST['givenWord']).")#iu", $downloadedPage, $result)); ` 
  
`// the regex is "#(d'isorder|di'sorder|dis'order|diso'rder|disor'der|disord'er|disorde'r|disorder‌​')#iu"`

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... Is this ok with you?

```
<?php
function find_stresses($word, $haystack) {
    $pattern = preg_replace('/[aeiou]/', '\0\'?', $word);
    $pattern = "/\b$pattern\b/";
    // word = 'disorder', pattern = "diso'?rde'?r"
    preg_match_all($pattern, $haystack, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

$hay = "something diso'rder somethingelse";
find_stresses('disorder', $hay);
// => array(diso'rder)
```

You didn't specify if there can be more than one match, but if not, you could use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all` (faster). For example, in Italian language we have `àncora` and `ancòra` :P

Obviously if you use `preg_match`, the result would be a string instead of an array.

Comment: Since you have basically the same code as @PaulH The same answer: Except for the one result which doesn't contain any apostrophe yes (the searched string has to contain an apostrophe). But my question was if I can do this with just a regex pattern (I forgot to write that I'm only interested in seeing if I can do this just with the regex pattern and not depend on any function).

Comment: Because of the dynamic nature of the search (a word inserted by an user), you cannot do it with regexp alone. Dynamic problem => dynamic pattern

Answer (score 0):

Based, on your code, and the requirements that no function is called and disorder is excluded. I  think this is what you want. I have added a test vector.

```
<pre>
<?php
// test code
$downloadedPage = "
there is some disorde'r
there is some disord'er in the example
there is some di'sorder in the example
there also' is some order in the example
there is some disorder in the example
there is some dso'rder in the example
";

$word = 'disorder';
preg_match_all("#".preg_replace("#[aeiou]#", "$0'?", $word)."#iu"
    , $downloadedPage
    , $result
);
print_r($result);
$result = preg_grep("#'#"
    , $result[0]
);
print_r($result);

// the code you need
$word = 'also';
preg_match("#".preg_replace("#[aeiou]#", "$0'?", $word)."#iu"
    , $downloadedPage
    , $result
);
print_r($result);
$result = preg_grep("#'#"
    , $result
);
print_r($result);
```

Working demo: https://eval.in/207312

Comment: Except for the one result which doesn't contain any apostrophe yes (the searched string has to contain an apostrophe). But my question was if I can do this with just a regex pattern (I forgot to write that I'm only interested in seeing if I can do this just with the regex pattern and not depend on any function).

Comment: Code adapted to match requirements that no function is called and disorder is excluded